# Background Image doesn't display in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm coding a very basic page in HTML/CSS and I want to put a background-image which is a link with an URL in a div element. My code works in Safari (Mac) and Firefox but doesn't work in Chrome.

I absolutely want to put this background-image using style attribute directly in the tag because it will be an image recovered from database.

I already try to reload cache few times but it still doesn't work in Chrome navigator.

I imagine that the solution is a parameter to activate in Chrome but I don't know what.

```html
<div class="ad-title" style="background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/350/?46548);">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Saepe enim omnis autem ex eum expedita voluptate.</h1>
      <p>Repudiandae vel laborum dicta. Et delectus reprehenderit et nostrum in dolores. Veniam natus sit quae nulla possimus quos.</p>
      <p class="h2">
        <strong>1 chambres</strong> pour <strong>101&euro;</strong> par nuit
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Réserver</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you put the image URL in Chrome's address bar, does it show the image?

Comment: Any console errors in chrome ? Seems to work fine in JSFiddle on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/qyj0dsv9/

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes the image link works. When I am in my page and that I inspect element I can see that the image is good load.

Comment: @ThomasLeNaour Have you tried restarting your computer? I know that's something that went out years ago, but for Chrome it might help.

Comment: @RishabhKumar No there is no console errors in chrome inspector.

Comment: I specify that I'm working with Symfony framework, I don't know if that means something hut I find weird that the background image perfectly works in Firefox and Safari but not in Chrome.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just tried to restart my computer but the problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class `ad-title` is conflicting with `Chrome AdBlock extension` classes. You need to be disable the extension or you can try in `incognito mode`.

I just have changed the name `ad-title` to `title` and it works perfectly.

Here is the solution:

https://codepen.io/ydhiman20/pen/GadWZo

Comment: You're right it works now, I don't know why the class ad-title doesn't work because I have no CSS... but you found the solution thank you very much !

Comment: (I changed the formatting because it looked like you were quoting something for the first paragraph.)

Comment: @ThomasLeNaour Do you have any ad-blocking add-ons in your Chrome? Perhaps it was picking up on the name "ad-title" and blocking it because of that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I have AdBlock, maybe that's why the class ad-title didn't work. I will try to disable it and check if it works, it could be good to know that ad-title class doesn't work with AdBlock.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I confirm, "ad-title" class works when my AdBlock extension is disabled. It's good to know. Well seen !

Comment: @ThomasLeNaour Your class are conflicting with the adblock extension. You need to be change the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it works in Firefox, Safari and also in Chrome.

Try using an incognito window in Chrome and if it works, it's a cache problem.

Comment: It works in an incognito window you're right, thank you very much ! I had yet reload my caches...

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling with this issue I figured up an easy solution to avoid this behavior of Chrome: I just cut the line of "background-image" of the .css file and pasted it in the object in the style property. It works perfect.